# Adicionar botão para inserir shorcodes no menu da construção de pagina do Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Estou estudando como fazer coisas para o Wordpress, consegui fazer um plugin que cria um formulário com múltiplas telas e opções de campos e botões.

Até agora as opções que passo no shortcodes é necessário saber do código para saber o que opções colocar e quais as palavras chaves das opções. O que eu quero é adicionar um botão que abre um modal onde nele a o usuario vai setar as opções, depois clica em inserir e gera o shortcode na pagina.

O menu que estou falando é o que é usado para formatar o texto da pagina. A estrutura que vi é a da div com `class="mce-toolbar-grp mce-container mce-panel mce-stack-layout-item mce-first"`.

Para entender o que quero fazer esse é um trecho do meu plugin:

```
function mf_container($atts, $content = null) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array (
        "table" => false,
        "user" => false,
        "redirect" => false,
    ), $atts ) );
    if($user && !is_user_logged_in()){
        return  'É necessario estar logado';
    }

    $content = do_shortcode($content);
    $content = str_replace("<br />","",$content);
    $content = str_replace("<p>","",$content);
    $content = str_replace("</p>","",$content);

    $header = "<form action='' method='post'>
            <input type='hidden' name='action' value='mult_form_submited'/>";

    if ($table){
        $header .= "<input type='hidden' name='table' value='".$table."'/>";
    }

    if ($redirect){
        $header .= "<input type='hidden' name='redirect' value='".$redirect."'/>";
    }

    if($user == "logged"){
        $header .= "<input type='hidden' name='user' value='".$user."'/>";
    }

    return $header . $content . "</form>";
}

add_shortcode('mult_form','mf_container');
```

nesse código o usuário pode passar por parâmetro, as opções de gerar uma tabela passando o nome da tabela na opção "table", passar opções do tipo de usuário que tem acesso ao formulário na opção "user", e se ele quer que a apos submeter a resposta ele quer ser redirecionado para uma pagina em especifico na opção "redirect".

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso? Quais as referencias de hook? Procurei no codex, mas até agora não faço ideia nem de como procurar por isso.

Obrigado comunidade!!!